# Magento 1.9:check out page not redirect to sucess page with event sales_order_place_after

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, module, extensions

I am beginner to magento & trying to develop a module for sending message when any order placed, with this module i am able to generate(send/recive) message but check out page not redirect to success page

`etc/config.php`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Sms>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Abc_Sms>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <abc_sms>
                <class>Abc_Sms_Model</class>
            </abc_sms>
        </models>
         <events>
            <sales_order_place_before><!-- observe the event -->
                <observers>
                    <abc_sms>
                        <class>abc_sms/observer</class>
                        <method>newCheckout</method>
                    </abc_sms>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Model/Oberver.php

```
<?php 
class Abc_Sms_Model_Observer
{
    public function newCheckout($observer)
    {
        $order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $order_no = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($order_id);

        $billing_address = $order->getBillingAddress(); 
        $billing_telephone = $billing_address->getTelephone();

        $msg = "Thank you for your purchase! Your order # is: ".$order_no;
        //sms api start

        $ch = curl_init();
        $user="****@gmail.com:****";
        $receipientno = $billing_telephone; 
        $senderID="TEST SMS"; 
        $msgtxt = $msg; 
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,  "http://api.mVaayoo.com/mvaayooapi/MessageCompose");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user=$user&senderID=$senderID&receipientno=$receipientno&msgtxt=$msgtxt");
        $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
        if (empty ($buffer)) {
            echo " buffer is empty ";
        } else {
            echo $buffer;
        } 
        curl_close($ch);
        //sms api 
    }    
}
?>
```

Thanks in Advance for help

Comment: enable log and check error

Comment: are you able to log in the observer's newcheckout function

Comment: you are using <sales_order_place_before> try to use <sales_order_place_after> in the config

Comment: are you able to log anything in the log file in the newcheckout function ?

Comment: i already use both <sales_order_place_before> & <sales_order_place_after> & also used these events <checkout_type_onepage_save_order> &<checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after> because my theme using one page checkout but result is same

Comment: when you want this>after Payment is done ... or immediate order place .

Comment: have you create module xml file  Abc_Sms.xml file?

Comment: are you able to log anything in the log file in the newcheckout function ?

Comment: @Amit Bera yes i create the Abc_Sms.xml in app/etc/modules

Comment: @AmitBera i want this immediate order place

Comment: remove curl  code check that pages is going to success page?

Comment: @PradeepSanku yes i can print info in newcheckout function

Comment: @AmitBera i am using external API code with curl if i remove this then sms is not generated

Comment: yes.understardard. Please remove curl code for checking page will properly redirection success page

Comment: @AmitBera i remove all codes related to curl & it redirect to success page but sms is not generated

Comment: @Dinesh,it may be your sms api issue.... it may need GET request instead of POST request

Answer (score 1):

In your etc/config.xml

You should use

```
<sales_order_place_after>
```

instead of

```
<sales_order_place_before>
```

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after><!-- observe the event -->
        <observers>
            <abc_sms>
                <class>abc_sms/observer</class>
                <method>newCheckout</method>
            </abc_sms>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```